# Using も in place of を

Tags: grammar, particles, jlpt, particle-も

I'm  currently trying to get back into studying Japanese. I want to take the JLPT N3 this summer. To get myself in the mode for this I am first looking at the N4 tests on the JLPT website.

The reading parts and kanji comprehension are no challenge for me. I can get through the vast majority of that without trouble and where I do slip up I can understand why.

Grammar however...grammar is the devil.

One of the supposedly easiest questions on the test is as follows-

> わたしの父は中国語も英語ｘ話せます

My instinct was for the answer to be を. も means in addition, so you have to have an actual action for the も to be in addition to, right?

No. It turns out the answer is も. I fail and I don't understand the reasons. Can anyone explain why in this context を is incorrect and　も is right?

It is a bit of an unusual sentence and a break from textbook patterns of the additional も. The way I'm used to is one person says I like y/I come from z, and the other person says 私も. Its not a particle I generally see used too often in this also sense, where I see it its usually as a negative.
To have the も come first like this confuses me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> わたしの父は中国語も英語も話せます。
>   My father can speak both Chinese and English.

～も～も is how you say "both ... and ..." in Japanese. It works with all particles, as も does by itself, i.e. usually replaces は, が, を and follows へ, に, etc.

It also works with more than two も's, e.g.

> わたしの父は中国語も英語もドイツ語も話せます。
>   My father can speak (all of) Chinese, English and German.

The point is that everything in the list is marked by も. If you said

> わたしの父は中国語も英語を話せます。

it just sounds wrong, but if it means anything, one would have to assume that も replaces が, which would give

> As for my father, his Chinese can also speak English.

Comment: How do we know this action is をed however?
I'm sure I remember that in lists it is only the additional things that need も whilst the last one has the standard particle?  Totally wrong?

Comment: For と you can say AとBを食べた; for も every item in the list needs it.

Comment: Oh...is there a particular reason も　is used here rather than と？

Comment: @Tor I think you can think of と as a simple, non-emphatic (and all-inclusive, as opposed to や) "and": My father can speak Chinese and English.

も...も, on the other hand, seems to place emphasis on the fact that multiple things can be done/are being done: My father speaks Chinese as well as/in addition to English.

Comment: @Tor: It is worth getting on top of this because there are plenty more "compound particles" that can be used to give a series or list of items and act in the same fashion (でも、し、といい　etc)