# What does this structure (～ + も + verb/adjective) mean?

Tags: grammar, syntax, particle-も

What does `Noun-verb + も + する` mean? I'm not even sure this is actually a structure. I found it in these 2 sentences:

> 1. 昨日のパーティーは料理もおいしかったし、雰囲気もよかった。（料理 [も] 美味しかった [し]）
> 2. リサはよく勉強 [も] する [し]、アルバイト [も] します。

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Those two sentences show the most basic usage of the particle も. も is a marker which means "also". From [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Japanese/Grammar/Basic_Particles#The_.22also.22_marker_.E3.82.82) (emphasis mine):

> **The "also" marker も**
>   も is quite simply a marker that says "also". **It replaces the particles は, が and を** but can also follow other particles. This can also be used to form a large list of words all acting as though one of the basic particles (は, を, or が) were affecting the whole list.
>
> しょうねん も しょうじょ も じょせい も だんせい も にんげん です。    Boys, girls, women and men are human.

In your first example sentence, the two が were replaced by も. In your second example, the two を were replaced by も.

> 1. 「料理**が**おいしかった」「雰囲気**が**よかった」 → 「料理**も**おいしかった」「雰囲気**も**よかった」
> 2. 「リサは勉強**を**する」「リサはアルバイト**を**する」　→　「リサは勉強**も**する」「リサはアルバイト**も**する」

Related question:

- [Using も in place of を](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14739/5010)