# What is the meaning of やかおもすぐ?

Tags: translation

What's the meaning of "やかおもすぐ" here in this sentence?

> あったひとのなまいやかおもすぐ覚えることができるんです

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 会った人の名前や顔もすぐ覚えることができるんです ("[He] can also remember the name and the face of people [he] has met.").

- 名前【なまえ】 "name" (なまい should be a typo)
- や "and" (See: [The many ways to say "and" in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/474/5010))
- 顔【かお】 "face"
- も "also" (this replaces the direct object marker を. See: [Using も in place of を](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14739/5010))
- [すぐ](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%9B%B4%E3%81%90) "at once"
- 覚える "memorize, learn"